# SQL error while running script with spring boot

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to populate my database as I start my project:

1. Spring-Boot
2. H2 embedded database

this is the script:

```
INSERT INTO 'VET' VALUES (1, 'AAAA', 'BBBB');
```

here is my entity in Java:

```
@Entity
public class Vet extends BaseClass{

//  @Id
//  @GeneratedValue
//  private int id;
    @NotNull(message="{NotNull}")
    @Size(min=2,max=15,message="{Size}")
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(message="{NotNull}")
    @Size(min=2,max=15,message="{Size}")
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    ...
}

@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

and as I start Spring, this is the StackTrace:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO 'VET'[*] VALUES (1, 'AAAA', 'BBBB')"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO 'VET' VALUES (1, 'AAAA', 'BBBB') [42001-192]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIdentifierWithSchema(Parser.java:3130) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5365) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1053) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:413) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:317) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:289) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:254) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:560) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:501) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1202) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:170) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:158) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:473) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
```

Of course the name of the script is *data.sql* and its located in resources folder, it's obviously reading the script accordingly to the stack trace. I don't understand the part with identifier

////EDIT

ok so I tried something like this:

```
INSERT INTO VET('id', 'first_name', 'last_name') VALUES (1, 'AAAA', 'BBBB');
```

and that's the error

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO VET('id'[*], 'first_name', 'last_name') VALUES (1, 'AAAA', 'BBBB')"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO VET('id', 'first_name', 'last_name') VALUES (1, 'AAAA', 'BBBB') [42001-192]
```

but when I go with:

```
INSERT INTO VET VALUES (1, 'AAAA', 'BBBB');
```

**build is successful**

so for educational purposes only why does the first option give errors?

Comment: `'VET'` is a string. it is NOT a field identifier. That'd be **JUST** `VET`, without the quotes.

Comment: You have used single quotes around `VET` instead of reverse quotes

Comment: `INSERT INTO VET(id, firstName, lastName) VALUES (1, 'AAAA', 'BBBB');`

Comment: Identifiers either need double quotes `"` or no quotes at all (which is **highly** recommended)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have quotes around your column names or table names.

```
INSERT INTO VET(id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (1, 'AAAA', 'BBBB')
```